# How does the Savage Land manage to exist in Antarctica?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-the-animated-series

I've been rewatching the old X-Men animated series, and it sparked the realisation that the Savage Land is actually located in Antarctica.

In-universe, how is this physically possible? The Savage Land is described as a tropical rain forest! I think that it's technically located underneath some layers of rock, in Antarctica. But even so, how is its climate explained?

Comment: Of all the impossible things in X-Men, the one you question is a rain forest underneath Antarctica?

Comment: I think this would be best on worldbuilding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Because of super advanced, 200 million year old alien technology of course.

It was created by the [Nuwali](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Nuwali):

> The Nuwali are one of the oldest intelligent races in the Universe, they achieved high levels of technology and devlopment millions years before most species.

So their super advanced tech trumps any logical argument as to how a tropical rain forest could possibly exist in the middle of Antarctica.

---

But, it's surrounded by a massive ring of volcanoes. So you could reasonably (not really) assume they produce enough heat in order to sustain the tropical climate:

> The [Savage Land](http://marvel.com/universe/Savage_Land) is a tropical region surrounded by volcanoes deep in Antarctica, created over 200 million years ago by the alien Nuwali as one of several planetary "game preserves" for the mysterious godlike [Beyonders](http://marvel.com/universe/Beyonders).
>
> When Earth's continents shifted circa 50 million BC, **the Nuwali augmented the Land's volcanoes to preserve its tropical status**.

Comment: I have just hit the episode where it explains  that there are Volcanos all over!

I guess this is the most proper answer I'm going to get!